# Is there a link for promoting the site newsletter?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I'd really like to promote our site's newsletter on Twitter, however **I'm having trouble finding a link to it**. Any reference to it seems to have disappeared altogether since I subscribed!

**Is this available somewhere?**

Related: [Add link to view newsletter on a web page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100690/6651) (on Meta SO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now:

http://stackexchange.com/newsletters/promote?site=sharepoint.stackexchange.com

We're still deciding where/how to link to this page from within the SE sites, but feel free to start spreading it now!

Answer (score 1):

I have just subscribed to newsletter by using this link: http://stackexchange.com/newsletters

But you need to use filter first and I didn't found way to pass filter trough query string.

I unsubscribed and looked around SPSE for link. I think I saw it once before but now I cannot find it.

I think this is preview of current newsletter: http://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=sharepoint.stackexchange.com

on second look this is maybe just preview because content seems out of date.

Comment: Something close to the preview would be perfect if it also had a "Subscribe" link on it! Thanks for finding that link.

Comment: The preview is always up-to-date.